# Undefined name 'stdout' issue in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio, dart

I have installed dart extension in Visual Studio but, it shows the given error `Error: Undefined name 'stdout'`.

```
void main() {

  stdout.write("Enter one number");

  var a = stdin.readLineSync();
}
```

Comment: Do you have `import 'dart:io';`?

Comment: Is it Visual Studio Code as mentioned in the title or Visual Studio as mentioned in the text and tag?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the top-level properties, [`stdout`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.2/dart-io/stdout.html) and [`stdin`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.2/dart-io/stdin.html), you must import the Dart library [`dart:io`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.2/dart-io/dart-io-library.html):

```dart
import 'dart:io'; // add this line to the beginning of your file

void main() {
  stdout.write("Enter one number");
  var a = stdin.readLineSync();
}
```